# Adding IF statements into Excel - If Column M = ### then Column N = $Amount but there are multiple M Values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm tracking sponsors and want to auto-populate the value of the sponsorship when typing in the title of the sponsor level.

Column M houses the titles of the sponsors and Column N tracks the $amount for that sponsorship.

Title Sponsor = $5,000.00
Barrel Sponsor = $2,500.00
Keg Sponsor = $1,000.00
Growler Sponsor = $500.00
Pint Sponsor = $250.00

So if I type "Barrel Sponsor" in column M I want column N to automatically put $2,500 as the value and so on for all levels. I am having trouble writing that formula.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! What have you done so far? What is the problem as what you are asking is very simple?

Comment: How does your data currently look? I assume you have a master list somewhere which connects the sponsor name with the value? If so, then I would use VLOOKUP() instead of an IF()

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try the formula `=IFNA(VLOOKUP(M1,{"Title Sponsor",5000;"Barrel Sponsor",2500;"Keg Sponsor",1000;"Gowler Sponsor",500;"Pint Sponsor",250},2,FALSE),"")`. Please remember cells of column N as Currency.

[image]

If there is any misunderstanding, please share us with more details.